# No button to create a fourth bounty on my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

I have this question: [How can I compact my Scrap Mechanic logic down?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/384003/). I want to add a fourth bounty of 50 rep, but the button is no longer there. The only bounty-related button is saying that it has been eligible since March 30th.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm uncertain how much another bounty will help, since the game doesn't appear all that popular among the Arqade community (only 1 question for it), but I've gone ahead and tossed a 500 rep bounty on it. Hopefully it'll help draw out an answer.

Comment: @Wipqozn Understandable, and thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each time you add a new bounty to the same question, the minimum amount of reputation that you can offer is doubled. From the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

Your first bounty cost 50 rep, the second 100, then someone else offered a third bounty on the question, and right now you don't have enough reputation to offer the 200 you'd need for the next bounty.